# How can I connect to a ms-access database from vba in excel?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to connect to an ms-access database from Excel by using VBA code, but I receive the error message "not valid password". I have an office 365 subscription.

I have tried passwords with only numbers, only words, putting a ";" character at the end of the password.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword"
cn.Open conexion
```

Comment: Try changing `accdb` to `mdb` and check whether it works.  Or try printing the value in `MyDbPassword` and see what it is.

Comment: Silly question, I assume you changed `MyDbPassword` to your actual password and `C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb` to your actual file path?

Answer (score 0):

From [Connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/):

> ### Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0
>
> #### Standard security
>
> `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
>   Persist Security Info=False;`
>
> #### With database password
>
> This is the connection string to use when you have an Access 2007 - 2013 database protected with a password using the "Set Database Password" function in Access.
>
> `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
>   Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;`
>
> Some reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also that some characters might cause trouble. If you are having problems, try change password to a short one with normal characters.
>
> Note! Reports say that a database encrypted using Access 2010 - 2013 default encryption scheme does not work with this connection string. In Access; try options and choose 2007 encryption method instead. That should make it work. We do not know of any other solution. Please get in touch if other solutions is available!

---

Based on their recommendation try to change the password to a short one under **14 characters**.

Additionally, in your example, you did leave off the semicolon `;` after your password.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I quote this solution posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13612ba0-f8cf-4c5d-b1db-96076e8ade70/error-while-connecting-access-2010-with-vba?forum=accessdev):

*"(...)First of all, remove the password, and then go into Access->File->Options->Client Settings->Advanced and check "use legacy encryption". Now we can recreate the password and give it a try."*

Keep in mind this option is less safe than "use predetermined encryption"